# How to comment SQL queries in SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, comments, sql-comments

I have 3 SQL queries in SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) as shown here - now, I want to comment them:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM test.admin.store_category

SELECT * 
FROM test.admin.store_product

SELECT * 
FROM test.admin.store_user
```

Are there any ways to comment them?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**single-line comments with "--"**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/comment-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) and [**multi-line comments with "/* */"**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/slash-star-comment-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) as shown below:

```sql
-- single-line comments

-- SELECT * FROM test.admin.store_category

SELECT * FROM test.admin.store_product

-- SELECT * FROM test.admin.store_user
```

```sql
/* multi-line comments */

/*
SELECT * FROM test.admin.store_category

SELECT * FROM test.admin.store_product
*/

SELECT * FROM test.admin.store_user
```